# Trouble using openpyxl to read row values

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to read the row values in two columns (A and B).

This is my current code:

```
import openpyxl as op
wb = op.load_workbook ('Canopy\Scripts\De Velliers.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']; colA = ws.columns[1]; row = ws.row[1]                        
for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        C_vel = np.array(cell.value) / (A_c * rho)       
wb = op.load_workbook('Canopy\Scripts\De Velliers.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']; colB = ws.columns[2]; row = ws.row[2]
for row in ws.row:
    for cell in row:
        P_s3 = P_t1 * np.array(cell. value)
        P_t3 = P_s3 + (rho * sp.sqrt(C_vel))/2.
        print (cell. value)
    print "C_vel:",C_vel
    print "P_s3:",P_s3
    print "P_t3:",P_t3
    print"_________" 
wb = op.load_workbook('Canopy\Scripts\De Velliers.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet4']
for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        T_t3 = ((((P_t3 / P_t1)**((k - 1) / k)) - 1) * T_t1)/(cell.value) + T_t1
        T_s3 = T_t3 - (sp.sqrt(C_vel)) / (c_p * 2.)
        rho_ new = P_s3 / (T_s3 * R) 
        print (cell. value)
        print "T_t3:",T_t3
        print "T_s3:", T_s3
        print "rho_new:", rho_new
        print "________"
```

When I try and run this, I get the following error:

> ```
>      25 wb = op.load_workbook ('Canopy\Scripts\De Velliers.xlsx')
> ---> 26 ws = wb['Sheet1']; colA = ws.columns[1]; row = ws.row[1]
>      27 for row in ws.rows:
>      28     for cell in row:
> ```
>
> Attribute Error: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'row'

How would I fix this?

Comment: Less haste = more speed. The exception is perfectly clear. You need to use `ws.rows` as you do in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The exception could be avoided by replacing 'row' with 'rows' in a couple of places.e.g.:

```
...
wb = op.load_workbook('Canopy\Scripts\DeVelliers.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
colA = ws.columns[1]
row = ws.rows[1]
for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        ...
```